# handlebars.js: change content dynamically on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm trying to change content based on a select field change.

"Monthly" will be the default option on page load. If the user changes the select value to "yearly", I want to replace `regularPrice` with the yearly one (based on the selected amount of users).

Is there some way I can dynamically change the `pricingOption`? For example, from `{{pricingOptions.monthly.regularPrice}}` to `{{pricingOptions.yearly.regularPrice}}` and also show the correct price based on the selected amount of users?

Is this possible with handlebars.js?

Thanks!

```
<select>
  <option>Pricing</option>
  <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option>Number of users</option>
  {{#each pricingOptions.monthly}}
    <option value="{{id}}">{{optionLabel}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>

<span>{{pricingOptions.monthly.regularPrice}}</span>
```

```
var productList = {
  pricingOptions: {
    monthly: [
      {
        id: 1,
        optionLabel: "1 user",
        regularPrice: 10.00
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        optionLabel: "2 users",
        regularPrice: 20.00
      }
    ],
    yearly: [
      {
        id: 1,
        optionLabel: "1 user",
        regularPrice: 100.00
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        optionLabel: "2 users",
        regularPrice: 200.00
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Render both, hide/show via js.

Comment: Have you looked at using handlebar [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) helper?